# return this-> command in C++

Tags: c++, return, this

return this->
what is that mean in C++

..

```
using namespace std;

IOM ConfigurationManager::getIOM(int iomId) {
  return this->IOMs[iomId];
```

..

the relevant part of the whole code is above.

The code that I wrote is from a huge project which was waiting for someone to finish. I am not good at C++ but I need to learn more not to lose that job. Anyway, the project is full of "return this->...." which I thought unnecessary, that's why I asked is there smt special that we should use that notation

Comment: Please read a C++ book. You could have just coded `return IOMs[iomId];` assuming `IOMs` is a member data field of the `ConfigurationManager` or some of its superclasses.

Comment: Is the problem "this" or "->"?

Comment: `this` is usually optional

Comment: @jrok i actually googled that...

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code simply means that the `IOM` at index `iomId` in the `IOMs` array in the `ConfigurationManager` object is returned. Note that the `this->IOMs` is the same as `IOMs` in this case, thus it seems the `this` is only there for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a pointer to the current object. The `->` operator allow you to access a member inside a pointer to an object.

Thus `return this->IOMs[iomID]` returns the IOM object in the current ConfigurationManager at index iomID.